# How can a user with less than 2000 rep accept or reject suggested edits?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, suggested-edits, badges

Here is a screenshot of my "select your next badge" window.

[image: select your next badge window]

As you can see in the screenshot, my rep was 1905 but I have 1/100 for proofreader badge. I took that screenshot recently, but I have been seeing that 1/100 for quite a long time now. I know that a user with less than 2000 rep doesn't have [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) Moderation Privilege. So, how was it possible for me to get that 1/100 for proofreader?

I have a *suspicion* though. I think that 1/100 came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757678/qstringlist-in-pyqt5) of mine. I get this *suspicion* because, as far as I remember I once edited that question without logging in. Also, you can see that the question was edited my [Mr. Community♦︎](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

---

I am tagging this question with "bug" tag, because I had to choose one from "discussion" and "bug", and the latter seemed right to me, though I *want to think* that this is not a bug!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A user can accept or reject suggested edits on their own posts, regardless of their reputation (so long as they were not already accepted/rejected by the community), and that is indeed what you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7465369):

> [image]

You can see the list of all your review decisions in your profile → Activity → all actions → reviews.

Comment: Maybe change the badge description to "Approve or reject 100 suggested edits on other users posts", just to make it crystal  clear? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I like that idea! And we both seem to have something in common :)

Comment: Just to make it a little clearer, what was happening there? What I understand is an anonymous user (which AFAIR was me, not logged in) suggested an edit, the user named Ottavio Campana rejected the edit, and then in a short time I logged in and approved my own edit. Am I correct? One more thing- what is the ratio of approve/reject for a suggested edit to be accepted/rejected, if there is anything like that?

Comment: @Shadowfax - it is all in the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)...

Comment: @Sha (huh, so weird! ;)) the **edit** is not yours, what you did, and what you get that badge for, is **reviewing** the edit, i.e. deciding "is this a good edit? Bad edit?" which is vital part of the self moderating SE model.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the edit was, I think, my own! Like I said, I did edit that question once (using improve this question option) **without being logged in**. This I think is the reason why the edit is shown to be done by **Community**.

Comment: @Sha no. You were logged in for sure, otherwise you couldn't have done the review. And choosing the Improve review action means "Approve, then edit". So the review action itself is Approve, and then you also add a new edit. Community appears due to technical reasons, feel free to jump by to chat to further discuss this. :)